# Как вернуть Promise массива в Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

Есть такой вот кусочек в функции:

```
var ind = 0;
var widgets_list = [];
for (ind = 0; ind < data.widgetsID.length; ind++) {
    db.Widget.findOne({'_id': data.widgetsID[ind]}).then(function(widget) {
        if (widget) {
            widgets_list.push(widget);
        }
    });
}
```

После него нужно сразу работать со списком выбранных значений. Проблема в том что выборка на каждое значение запускается асинхронно. И сразу после выполнения цикла список может быть просто незаполненным.

Попробовал в **Promise** обернуть, но как то, это не сильно помогло. Как правильно массивы в **Promise** заворачивать?

```
var list_promice = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    var w_list = [];
    var p_ind = 0;
    for(p_ind = 0; p_ind < data.widgetsID.length; p_ind++) {

        db.Widget.findOne({'_id': data.widgetsID[p_ind]}).then(function(widget) {
            if(widget) {
                w_list.push(widget);
            }
        });

    }
    resolve(w_list);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема не совсем там, где вы ее указали в вашем вопросе. Получать результирующий список (и работать с ним) нужно после того как будут выполнены все `db.Widget.findOne().then()`.

Вам нужен [Promise.all()](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise#promise-all-iterable)

```
var ind = 0,
    widgets_list = [],
    promises = [];
for (ind = 0; ind < data.widgetsID.length; ind++) {
    promises.push(db.Widget.findOne({'_id': data.widgetsID[ind]}).then(function(widget) {
        if(widget) {
            widgets_list.push(widget);
        }
    }));
}
Promise.all(promises).then(function() {
    // что-нибудь делаем с widgets_list
})
```