# Добавление координат Яндекс карт в массив

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Пытаюсь получить массив координат вида

```
[
    [55.75, 37.50], [55.75, 37.71], [55.70, 37.70]
]
```

Код

```
var coords = [];

for ( var i = 0; i < addresses.length; i++ )
{
    ymaps.geocode(addresses[i], {results: 1 }).then(function (res) {
        console.log(res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates()); // ok
        coords.push(res.geoObjects.get(0).geometry.getCoordinates());
    });
}

console.log(coords); // empty
```

На выходе получаю пустой массив :(

Comment: Потому что `console.log(coords);` выполняется раньше чем завершаются вызовы `geocode`. Читать про асинхронность и promise-ы

Comment: Да читал уже. Если бы я знал как решить данную проблему, я сюда бы не писал, логично ? Так что ваш ответ как минимум некорректен.

Comment: Этот вопрос задают несколько раз в неделю. http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/487996/190728 вот, например, одно из решений вашей проблемы.

Comment: Что ж, спасибо и на этом. Правда не совсем понятно каким образом это http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/487992/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%8C-promise-%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2-node-js/487996#487996 может помочь в решении моей проблемы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

реализация мульти-геокодера :

https://github.com/deflexor/ymaps/blob/patch-1/multi-geocoder.js

```
* Класс для геокодирования списка адресов или координат.
 * @class
 * @name MultiGeocoder
 * @param {Object} [options={}] Дефолтные опции мультигеокодера.
 */
function MultiGeocoder(options) {
    this._options = options || {};
}

/**
 * Функция множественнеого геокодирования.
 * @function
 * @requires ymaps.util.extend
 * @see http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/util.extend.xml
 * @requires ymaps.util.Promise
 * @see http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.x/ref/reference/util.Promise.xml
 * @name MultiGeocoder.geocode
 * @param {Array} requests Массив строк-имен топонимов и/или геометрий точек (обратное геокодирование)
 * @returns {Object} Как и в обычном геокодере, вернем объект-обещание.
 */
MultiGeocoder.prototype.geocode = function (requests, options) {
    var self = this,
        size = requests.length,
        defer = new ymaps.vow.defer(),
        geoObjects = new ymaps.Collection();

    requests.forEach(function (request, index) {
        ymaps.geocode(request, ymaps.util.extend({}, self._options, options))
            .then(
                function (response) {
                    var geoObject = response.geoObjects.get(0);

                    geoObject && geoObjects.add(geoObject, index);
                    --size || defer.resolve({ geoObjects : geoObjects });
                },
                function (err) {
                    defer.reject(err);
                }
            );
    });

    return defer.promise();
};
```